# How can you obtain a symmetric adjacency matrix of an induced subgraph?

Tags: python, igraph

The complete graph on 4 vertices is represented as an edgelist as follows:

```
$ cat k4.edgelist 
0 1
0 2
0 3
1 2
1 3
2 3
```

Now, consider the following Python script using python-igraph:

```
from igraph import Graph

g=Graph.Full(4)
n=g.induced_subgraph(g.neighbors(0))
print n.get_adjacency().data

h=Graph.Read_Edgelist('k4.edgelist')
n=h.induced_subgraph(h.neighbors(0))
print n.get_adjacency().data
```

The output on executing is:

```
[[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0]]
[[0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0]]
```

I am confused, since I would expect the second line to be equal to the first. The [documentation for get_adjacency()](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#get_adjacency) has a parameter `type` which is set to `GET_ADJACENCY_BOTH` by default, thus the matrix should indeed be symmetric.

Is there a direct way of obtaining a symmetric adjacency matrix of an induced subgraph? I can surely do this via linear algebra, but the matrices I care about are large, so I'd like to do this as efficiently as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a directed graph. Make an undirected one:

```
h=Graph.Read_Edgelist('k4.edgelist', directed=False)
```